# The shiny package will not load after installation

Tags: r, shiny, htmltools

I tried:

```
install.packages('shiny')
library(shiny)
```

Got the following message:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘shiny’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> there is no package called ‘htmltools’
> In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘shiny’ was built under R version 4.0.5

I tried starting over and loading htmltools and then also the following error:

> Error in library(htmltools) : there is no package called 'htmltools'

Comment: go to the folders and manually delete them, reinstall after

Comment: Try installing `htmltools` again (`install.packages("htmltools")`), then install `shiny` again, then give it a try.